# Autowire service error after migrating to Symfony 3.4 - How to configure value explicitly?

Tags: symfony

I am migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. After adding the existing `AppBundle` to a fresh generated `Symfony 3.4` project I the following error:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController": argument
>   "$useDebugMode" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "bool", you
>   should configure its value expl     icitly

I found several other questions about this problem, but the solution always points to missing parameters in the `service.yml` file. However, as far as I can tell, this is not the problem here:

```
// CustomExceptionController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
...

class CustomExceptionController extends ExceptionController {   
    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, bool $useDebugMode, Translator $translator) {
        parent::__construct($twig, $useDebugMode);
        ...
    }

    ...
}


// services.yml
services:
    ...
    app.exception_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController
        arguments: ['@twig', '%kernel.debug%', "@translator.default" ]
```

I did not explicitly set/define `%kernel.debug%` in the `app/config/config.yml` but I assume that this is not necessary. Is it?

Thus the value of the `$useDebugMode` parameter IS set explicitly to the value of `%kernel.debug%`. So how to solve the error?

Comment: The problem is that when autowire is scanning your Controller directory and picks up CustomExceptionController it looks in the container for a service definition with an id of CustomExceptionController.  Your id is app.exception.controller so a match is not found and thus it tries to wire things up and chokes on the parameter.  Just change the id to the full class name and it should work.  Or exclude CustomExceptionController from autowire.

Answer (score 2):

```
// services.yml
services:
    ...
    app.exception_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController
        arguments:
           $useDebugMode: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Specify only `$useDebugMode` in your arguments list, other two will get autoinjected/autowired.

The `$useDebugMode` must be the same as in constructor.

Comment: While this refines things a bit it won't fix the actual problem.

Comment: Oh, on the top of my head, kernel.debug parameter could be resolved after service configuration. Try setting `$useDebugMode: true`

Comment: Read my comment under the original question.  The error is coming from something else completely.

Comment: If it passes the service configuration, then kernel.debug is resolved later and you should opt for a different parameter or injecting the whole container there which is not the best solution

Comment: Once again, this has nothing to do with the debug parameter and everything to do with the service id.  Make yourself a simple project and try it.  The error message is very common and perhaps a bit misleading.  If you plan on using autowire then you will encounter it and you will waste a lot of time (or at least I did) understanding what the real problem is.  After that it becomes trivial.

Comment: True. In that case, alias it to the class name, if you insist on using service id, and see if it happens again.